# Sorting objects based on property value in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I have a array of objects for use in D3 e.g

```
var cities = [
  { city: "London", country: "United Kingdom", index: 280 },
  { city: "Geneva", country: "Switzerland", index: 259 },
  { city: "New York City", country: "United States", index: 237 },
  { city: "Singapore", country: "Singapore", index: 228 },
  { city: "Paris", country: "France", index: 219 },
  { city: "San Francisco", country: "United States", index: 218 },
  { city: "Copenhagen", country: "Denmark", index: 217 },
  { city: "Sydney", country: "Australia", index: 215 },
  { city: "Hong Kong", country: "Hong Kong", index: 214 },
  { city: "Brisbane", country: "Australia", index: 208 }
}
```

I would like to order the objects in ascending order based on their cities.index property. So that I can display them as such in `D3.js`. Im sure there is a way of doing this in D3 but I am yet to figure it out when dealing with an array of objects.

Any help?

Comment: Why not just sort them in the array before using it?

Comment: Just pass `.sort()` a custom sorting function. You can access the `index` property of the objects and use to determine order. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

Comment: @TravisJ Ideally this is what I would like to do sorry for not being more descriptive

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous function to the Javascript [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort by `index`. D3 has a function [`d3.ascending`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#ascending) [(v 3.x)](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md)  that makes it easy to sort ascending:

```
cities.sort(function(x, y){
   return d3.ascending(x.index, y.index);
})
```

And here's the output:

```
[
 {"city":"Brisbane","country":"Australia","index":208},
 {"city":"Hong Kong","country":"Hong Kong","index":214},
 {"city":"Sydney","country":"Australia","index":215},
 {"city":"Copenhagen","country":"Denmark","index":217},
 {"city":"San Francisco","country":"United States","index":218},
 {"city":"Paris","country":"France","index":219},
 {"city":"Singapore","country":"Singapore","index":228},
 {"city":"New York City","country":"United States","index":237},
 {"city":"Geneva","country":"Switzerland","index":259},
 {"city":"London","country":"United Kingdom","index":280}
]
```

Comment: Why `stringify` the results? You don't really need it. :)

Comment: Just so the output in my console doesn't say `[Object, Object, Object, ...]`. But yeah, perhaps doesn't need to be in my answer.

Comment: What if some array objects have undefined values? It doesn't appear that `d3` sort deals with these cases.

Answer (score 6):

**Just [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the array before you use it in D3,** as [Travis J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026459/travis-j) mentioned in a comment. There's no reason to use D3 to sort ([`d3.ascending` is just a comparison wrapper anyway](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#ordering)).

*Also, note that you have a `}` where you want a `]` at the end of your declaration.*

---

You can access each object's properties as so:

```
cities.sort(function(a, b){
    return a["index"]-b["index"];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Casey Falk said `d3.sort` is an elegant method in d3 library. I code the following to solve my problem:

```
const axisGrid = svg.append("g")
const photoGroup = axisGrid.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(photo_data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

const photos = photoGroup.append("image");
photos.on("mouseenter", function(curItem) {
        // selection.sort(compare) https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#selection_sort
        photoGroup.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.photo == curItem.photo) { // make the current image element on top
            return 1
          } else {
            return -1
          }
        })
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to use d3 at all. There is a comment reference to `selection.sort` but that sorts DOM elements and not a generic array, which is what the question is about.