# Issue with summing and data manipulation in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data set that i'm trying to work with in js.D3 and i'm struggling.

The dataset has the following attributes:

1. Job Offers (Int)
2. City (String)
3. Date (DateTime)
4. Industry (String)
5. College Graduate (Boolean value)

I want to sum all job offers received by city by month and for some reason i'm coming up short and receiving an error.

First I have done the following to ensure I have clean data (I.E. no missing records etc):

`const cleanJobData = data.filter(d=> d.city !=="" && d.dateTime !=="" && d.jobOffer !== "" && d.jobOffer!== 0)`

I then tried to use `d3.rollup` to sum job offers by city:

```
const jobOffersByMonth = d3.rollup(cleanJobData,
                                           fcm => d3.sum(fcm, d=> d.jobOffer),
                                           d => d.dateTime.getMonth(), city => city.city);
```

This now gives me a map of months with corresponding totals for job offers by city.  I want to now sort this from greatest to least by number of offers per city.  if I try and use `d3.sort()` I receive an error that `d3.sort` is not a function.  What am I doing wrong here?

I also tried using a group function `const jobOffersByMonth = d3.group(cleanJobData, d => d.dateTime.getMonth(), v => v.city, fcm => d3.sum(fcm, v => v.jobOffers))` but I receive the error: `T is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `d3.sort` is trying to use the `Array` [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function on `d3` which is not an `Array` and therefore, it's true: `d3.sort is not a function`.

You would have to use `sort` on `jobOffersByMonth` (after converting it to an `Array` from a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is what is returned after doing a `rollup`) and create an appropriate function to pass to it, perhaps taking advantage of `d3`'s `ascending` or `descending`, like this user's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25168203/1168004 or

```
// given jobOffersByMonth looks something like:
// Map {
//      "{MONTH_NAME}" => int
// }
// we must first convert it into an Array to sort it 
// using Array.from(jobOffersByMonth) or [...jobOffersByMonth]

[...jobOffersByMonth].sort(function(x, y){
   return d3.ascending(x[1], y[1]); // could alternatively be descending
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the following code fulfill your requirement.

```js
const data = [{
    jobOffer: 23,
    city: 'mumbai',
    dateTime: new Date(2014, 1, 1),
    industry: 'aa',
  },
 {
    jobOffer: 23,
    city: 'mumbai',
    dateTime: new Date(2014, 2, 2),
    industry: 'aa',
  },
  {
    jobOffer: 23,
    city: 'delhi',
    dateTime: new Date(2012, 1, 1),
    industry: 'aa',
  },
  {
    jobOffer: 23,
    city: 'delhi',
    dateTime: new Date(2011, 2, 2),
    industry: 'aa',
  },
  {
    jobOffer: 23,
    city: 'pak',
    dateTime: new Date(2013, 1, 1),
    industry: 'aa',
  },
    {
    jobOffer: 23,
    city: 'delhi',
    dateTime: new Date(2011, 2, 2),
    industry: 'aa',
  },
]

const cleanJobData = data.filter(d => d.city !== "" && d.dateTime !== "" && d.jobOffer !== "" && d.jobOffer !== 0);

var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.dateTime.getMonth();
  })
 .key(function(d) {
  return d.city;
 })
  .rollup(function(leaves) {
    return d3.sum(leaves, function(d) {
      return d.jobOffer;
    })
  })
  .entries(cleanJobData)
 .map((data) => {
  return data.values.sort((a,b) => b.value - a.value);
 })


console.log(nested_data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.4.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this isn't by month.  The inner part is correct but it's not by month unfortunately

Comment: I have updated the current code, you can check it. I hope it will fulfill your requirement.